# Yii zii.widgets.CMenu css for multilevel submenu

Tags: php, css, yii

how can work correctly multilevel sub menus in  zii.widgets.CMenu?

for first level sub menu it works correctly ..
but when click for second level sub menu it hide the most parent level and when again click on parent

it shows correct open menus..

so i m not getting where to 
[image]

see attached image ..when click on **Sales Management** for first time it closes **'Configuration'** menu and when again click on **'configuration'** it shows correct as shown in image..
so at first click of **'Sales Management'** ==> **'Configuaration'** menu should not be closed..

how can i solve that..

code is as below

> $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(

```
   'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'sidebar-menu',
    ),
    'submenuHtmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'submenu',
    ),
    'encodeLabel' => false,
    'activeCssClass'=>'active',
    'activateParents'=>true,
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'label' => '<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>&nbsp;
                                    <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md">Configurations</span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right chevron-icon-sidebar"></i>',
            'url' => '#',
            'itemOptions' => array('class' => 'dropdown'),
            'linkOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'dropdown-toggle ',
                'data-toggle' => 'dropdown-menu',
            ),
            'visible' => true,
            'items' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Sales Management',
                    'url' => '',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'itemOptions' => array(
                        'class' => 'dropdown-submenu',
                    ),
                    'items' => array(
                        array(
                            'label' => 'Code Promo',
                            'url' => array('/backoffice/codePromo/index'),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'label' => 'Assurance',
                            'url' => array('/backoffice/assurance/index'),
                        ),
```

......................

Answer (score 1):

hi You can try it out like this

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
                            'items'=>array(
                                array('label'=>'Home',   'url'=>array('site/index')),
                                array('label'=>'Products', 'url'=>array('product/index'), 'items'=>array(
                                    array('label'=>'New Arrivals', 'url'=>array('product/new')),
                                    array('label'=>'Most Popular', 'url'=>array('product/index')),
                                    array('label'=>'Another', 'url'=>array('product/index'), 'items'=>array(
                                        array('label'=>'Level 3 One', 'url'=>array('product/new')),
                                        array('label'=>'Level 3 Two', 'url'=>array('product/index')),
                                        array('label'=>'Level 3 Three', 'url'=>array('product/index'), 'items'=>array(
                                            array('label'=>'Level 4 One', 'url'=>array('product/new')),
                                            array('label'=>'Level 4 Two', 'url'=>array('product/index')),
                                        )),
                                    )),
                                )),
                                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('site/login')),
                            ),
                        ));
```